# warning using Parallel::ForkManager but only in Windows

Tags: windows, perl, fork

I sometimes get this warning when using [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/~yanick/Parallel-ForkManager-1.18/lib/Parallel/ForkManager.pm) but only in Windows, not on a Unix based system. What does it mean and should I worry about it?

> child process '-17108' disappeared. A call to `waitpid` outside of
>   Parallel::ForkManager might have reaped it.

Here is the sample code from the [docs](http://search.cpan.org/~yanick/Parallel-ForkManager-1.18/lib/Parallel/ForkManager.pm) that my code is based on:

```
use LWP::Simple;
use Parallel::ForkManager;

my @links=(
    ["http://www.foo.bar/rulez.data","rulez_data.txt"],
    ["http://new.host/more_data.doc","more_data.doc"],
);

# Max 30 processes for parallel download
my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(30);

LINKS:
foreach my $linkarray (@links) {
    $pm->start and next LINKS; # do the fork

    my ($link, $fn) = @$linkarray;
    warn "Cannot get $fn from $link"
      if getstore($link, $fn) != RC_OK;

    $pm->finish; # do the exit in the child process
}

$pm->wait_all_children;
```

Comment: It means that the process ended and some other process reaped it calling waitpid before Parallel::ForkManager. Given that it happens only sometimes and on Windows could indicate a bug somewhere, I think.

Comment: @jira There are no other processes that could have reaped it.  What does 'reaped' mean anyway?

Comment: I think best would be to report it as a possible bug in Parallel::ForkManager.

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar issue and placing a sleep 1 before "$pm->start and next LINKS;"
fixed the issue. I guess its due to continues forking, where Perl lost track of the fork processes. I may be wrong!